# R: How can I save all objects within a functions local environment?

Tags: r, scope, save

Is there a way to use save.image() so that it saves the objects within the environment of a function?  Take this minimal example:

```
outside = "not in function"
testFun <- function(){
  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = 3
  save.image(file="environmentTest.Rdata")
}

testFun()
```

When I open environmentTest.Rdata, the object `outside` is there, but not `a`, `b`, or `c`. Is there a way to use `save.image()` (or another function) to save all the objects within the scope of the current function (without explicitly listing them)?

Comment: You can use `?local` to save it in a local environment

Comment: `save(list=ls(), file=...)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the indicated `save` command.

```
outside = "not in function"
testFun <- function(){
  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = 3
  save(list = ls(all.names = TRUE), file = "environment.RData")
}
testFun()

load("environment.RData", e <- new.env())
ls(e)
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: It might be worth adding that the reason this works is that the `name` argument of the `ls` function defaults to the current environment. If that were not the default, one would need to include `name = environment()` inside the `ls` call.